# How to add duration to metadata of files recorder by MediaRecorder

Tags: duration, mediarecorder, truncated, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I am recording video by [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) in Chrome. My code is similar to [an example from MediaStream docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API). I am receiving videos that do not have `Duration` metadata.

I compared it by `mediainfo` with exemplary webm file from:

> https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2020/03/file_example_WEBM_480_900KB.webm

On the left, there are metadata of file recorded by MediaRecorder, on the right from the exemplary webm file.

[image]

Detailed comparison on DiffChecker

> https://www.diffchecker.com/87G23lbX

There are three key differences:

In the file from MediaRecorder:

1. there is lacking `Duration`.
2. there is lacking `Bit rate`.
3. there is added `IsTruncated: Yes`.

In effect when I add this file to the video tag on website with controls attribute, then I can use controls only when file is displayed to the end.

I need to fix it and save non truncated files with this duration. Both frontend and backend solutions are accepted.

Comment: I fixed thanks to package https://github.com/yusitnikov/fix-webm-duration/blob/master/fix-webm-duration.js, but I am surprised that it is done by low-level access to sections of webm binary.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67041475/1066234

Answer (score 2):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640361/how-to-add-duration-to-metadata-of-files-recorder-by-mediarecorder/76580216#comment112538439_63640361) proposed by [daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6398044/daniel) works like a charm, which was to use the library from https://github.com/yusitnikov/fix-webm-duration to add the duration metadata to the webm Blob.